# Help me find flaws on my simple machines invention

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have a work to make an invention on simple machines. First of all I am sorry if my English is not very good or clear. As we all know, simple machines are used to simplify things in life and use less work (mechanical advantage). My concept is using a pulley to pull things up, but I want to use like a machine that needs to be stepped (lever type 3) to move the pulley. But I feel like there is a flaw to my invention, and feel very frustated. This is my concept visualization:
[image]

*`P.S: Sorry for the language usage (Image is semi-English and semi-Indonesian language)`*

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand? Do you want to get the red pulley to roll up the rope? Is the rope on the "pedal" not the same as the rope on the bucket? If you want to lift the bucket by repeatedly stepping on the pedal, you need some kind of ratcheting mechanism and a spring to return the pedal into its original position.

Comment: Hello kruemi and thanks for the reply. Yes I think you got what I mean, by stepping on the pedal. Although my goal is just to step on it once, it is ok for the concept to step on the pedal repeatedly. Can you explain more about me to this "ratcheting mechanism", considering I am only 8th grade and haven't learn it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think ratcheting mechanism is a simple machine.

Comment: Hello George, if it isn't, is there any other way I can do it? Or maybe should i replace the pedal with anything else? Any ideas? Big thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Hello Alves. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of simple machines is usually "sacrifice length to gain force". Or the opposite, but more rarely. You have incorporated a level and pulleys in your design. Let's analyze those.

- The lever

The first problem is that you have made a lever that, if you step on it, the weight will go down. But, it would already go down by gravity, this is not useful. You probably want to counteract gravity and make it go up, so something like this:

[image]

The other problem is the general idea of using a level with your foot. The thing is, you can't move your foot much. This means do not really have length to sacrifice to gain force. So, to use a lever with your foot, you have to either:

1. Use it to lift something very light with a single motion of the foot. It's hard to find a use for this, though. Also, it means that the edge of the lever would be really long a take much space.

[image]

2. Use it to lift a heavy weight, but your foot won't have enough room. To gain multiple times one floor's height, you'd probably want to jump from some roof:

[image]

Now that we got the lever "solved", let's discuss the pulley (which is much easier for you to do without being unrealistic).

Note that just having a pulley somewhere doesn't provide you an advantage. You have to use something like a snatch block:

[image]

This will indeed allow you to use a long rope to raise the weight with less effort:

[image]

Comment: Hello again. You see exactly what I see, it will not be enough to pull it up with just a single stomp on the pedal, unless like you said, jump from a really high place and most likely... die (f moment, dying for an experiment). That is also one of my problems. The concept is true, pulling. But I want to like, convert the pulling into something else, maybe stepping on a pedal (the work demands me to invent something new, something that is never made before). I would like to ask your recommended replacement for the pedal. Thank you again, George!

Comment: Will a wheel work fine (like a pirate wheel) ?

Comment: Hundreds of billions of people have lived, and many of them had to think smart solutions to a everyday problems. The only invention that might have not been made yet is a way to raise the weight, then let it free fall onto the head of the teacher that asks for impossible things.

Yeah, make a pirate wheel gather all that rope seems OK.

Comment: Thank you kind sir!